# What is the difference between a JFrame and a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm trying to make a Space Invaders game

```
public static SpaceInvaders spaceinvaders;

public static Renderer renderer;

// Constructor
public SpaceInvaders() {
    JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame();
    
    renderer = new Renderer();
    frame.add(renderer);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    gameDisplay g = new gameDisplay(); // a JFrame Form
    g.setVisible(true);
    g.gameScreen.add(frame); // gameScreen is a JPanel
    renderer.repaint();

}

public void repaint (Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}
```

If I run this, I get the expected result of a dialog box with a red rectangle filling it. But if I replace the JInternalFrame with a JFrame, I get an error saying

IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container

So what is the difference between a JInternalFrame and a JFrame, and why can I add a renderer to the former but not the latter?

Comment: `JFrame` is a "top level" container which is attached to a native peer.  In of itself, it can't be added to other containers (as you've discovered).  A `JInternalFrame` is a normal container which is decorated to look like a window (or at least one which is used as a "document" interface)

Comment: Oh, and don't override `repaint` in that way

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh ok, thank you. What's wrong with overriding repaint this way?

Comment: I'm not sure where it's coming from,`repaint(Graphics)` doesn't appear to be a Swing based method, but generally speaking, `repaint` (within Swing) is used to schedule a new paint pass for the component

Answer (score 0):

The full picture is that (J)Frame, (J)Dialog and (J)Window are special `Component`s that are intrisically tied to a platform native "peer" at some level. And you can't mix these peers. You may want to read something about OS toolkits and the UI windowing services they provide.

Swing was designed to rely on OS toolkits to the minimal extent possible. But a program can't show a window on the screen without using the OS toolkit